# Laravel - model policy in some routes not working

Tags: laravel-5, routes, laravel-middleware, policies

In a revision work - Laravel 5.8 -  I'm facing a strange behavior:

**app » Policies » CustomerPolicy**

```
public function create(User $user )
{
    dd($user);  //  for debugging purposes          
}
... 
public function update(User $user, Customer $customer)
{
    dd($customer);  //  for debugging purposes      
}
...
```

Registering the policy
**app » Providers » AuthServiceProvider**

```
protected $policies = [
    Customer::class => CustomerPolicy::class,
    // TRIED ALSO:   'App\Customer' => 'App\Policies\CustomerPolicy',
];
```

**routes » web**

```
Route::get( 'customers/create', 'CustomerController@create')->name( 'customers.create' )->middleware( 'can:create,customer' );
...
Route::get( 'customers/{customer}/edit', 'CustomerController@edit' )->name( 'customers.edit' )->middleware( 'can:update,customer' );   
Route::patch( 'customers/{customer}', 'CustomerController@update')->name( 'customers.update' )->middleware( 'can:update,customer' );
```

The strange thing is: the above first route - 'customers/create' - doesn't work, trying to access the page gets a 403 / forbidden code. But the other two - 'customers.edit', 'customers.update' -  work as expected !!?!.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, nonetheless I'm still wondering why didn't work with the simplified class name.

```
Route::get( 'customers/create', 'CustomerController@create')->name( 'customers.create' )->middleware( 'can:create,App\Customer' );
```